# Method for fixing compilation errors appearing in library code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to fix my last compilation error and I have run into one of those cases where the line that the error refers to is not in any of the code that I have written, but instead in some other standard library.

Obviously, the issue is caused by something **I** am doing, (ex. syntax in some file) however, there is no way to know which line of my code is calling the function that causes the error.  Going backwards doesn't work any better since the function could be called any number of times from my code.

Stuff like this:...

```
template<class _InIt,
    class _Ty> inline
    _InIt _Find(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, const _Ty& _Val, false_type)
    {   // find first matching _Val
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
        if (*_First == _Val)
            break;
    return (_First);
    }
```

Just doesn't tell me much about how to continue.

I know that if I could somehow step backward through the compilation process to find the last line of my code I could probably deduce the issue. (I tried to increase the logging verbosity of the compiler output but it didn't provide any useful info).

What is the best way to debug this sort of issue? Is there a method to step through the compilation process as you would with a standard debugger, or another standard way to work through the problem? Or is it one of those things that must just be worked through case by case.

For reference, I am using VS2013 with boost 1.59.0 and sfml 2.3.2 as dependencies. The specific error I'm dealing with is in xutility, but I am hoping for some more general insight.

Here is the complete error message:

```
Error 4 error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a
left-hand operand of type
'std::map<std::string,int,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const
_Kty,_Ty>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)     c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 3026 1 Engine
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything directly wrong at that line. What exactly is the error message you are getting? [Templates can lead to rather long and complex error listings that often refer to the instantiated template function - look at the first one and fix that first, before worrying about others]

Comment: Usually when the compiler finds a problem instantiating a template, it spits out a *huge* list of where and why it was trying to do so.  Please include the *full* error message.

Comment: I recognize the code style as part of the VS standard library. If this fails, you either use an iterator that isn't a real iterator, or have a type that doesn't have an `operator==` defined.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I added the full message. There is certainly nothing wrong with the library code in itself and I'm sure my arguments are just causing the template to fail but not in what manner.  Ideas about the specific case would be great but a more general idea of how to think about this issue would be better since i'm sure it will come up again... Maybe I just need to get better at interpreting those messy errors.

Comment: You are getting this error because you are instantiating the template incorrectly. Continue reading the error log, it will list a template instantiation stack, ending in your code.

Comment: This is probably still not the full error message. It should be followed by a 'stack' of template instantiations - the last of which is your own code.

Comment: In general it's: (1.) _read_ you messages (well!) and (2.) _keep at it_. It can be daunting, which is why I posted a answer with a guessed sample usage.

Comment: Extract a minimal example before posting here. Exactly your case is the reason that is a rule here. Please study the posting guidelines for further info.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt to be fair, the question is exactly about "I don't know how to handle error novels". So it is sort of self-referential that the OP doesn't know what to include.

Comment: It's written in the guidelines what to include, @sehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming from the part of the error message that you show, I'd expect "sane" code to be like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using Map = map<string, int>;

int main() {
    vector<Map> maps;

    Map target { { "one", 1 }, { "two", 2 } };

    auto match = std::find(maps.begin(), maps.end(), target);
}
```

The fact that you have an error, indicates, likely, that you messed up the "target" parameter. E.g.:

```
auto match = std::find(maps.begin(), maps.end(), "one");
```

Results in

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >' and 'const char *')
       { return *__it == _M_value; }
```

(*That's for GCC/libstdc++ which delegates the implementation this search to `find_if`, so the details are different*).

You can see the "stack" in the full error message:

```
clang++-3.6   -DNDEBUG -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic  -g -O3 -isystem /home/sehe/custom/nonius/include -isystem /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_60_0 -isystem /usr/include/python2.7 -I /tmp/autobahn-cpp/ -pthread -march=native -L /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/ -Wl,-rpath,/home/sehe/custom/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib  test.cpp   -o test
test.cpp:14:10: warning: unused variable 'match' [-Wunused-variable]
    auto match = std::find(maps.begin(), maps.end(), "one");
        ^
In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/map:60:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:63:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/predefined_ops.h:194:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >' and 'const char *')
        { return *__it == _M_value; }
                ~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:120:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization '__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<char const[4]>::operator()<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > *, std::vector<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > > > > >' requested here
        if (__pred(__first))
            ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:161:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__find_if<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > *, std::vector<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<char const[4]> >' requested here
    return __find_if(__first, __last, __pred,
            ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:3790:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__find_if<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > *, std::vector<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<char const[4]> >' requested here
    return std::__find_if(__first, __last,
                ^
test.cpp:14:23: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::find<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > *, std::vector<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > > > >, char [4]>' requested here
    auto match = std::find(maps.begin(), maps.end(), "one");
                    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_pair.h:214:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'pair' against 'map'
    operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:292:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator' against 'map'
    operator==(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:342:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator' against 'map'
    operator==(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:820:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '__normal_iterator' against 'map'
    operator==(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:827:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '__normal_iterator' against 'map'
    operator==(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:1065:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'move_iterator' against 'map'
    operator==(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:1071:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'move_iterator' against 'map'
    operator==(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/ext/new_allocator.h:139:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'new_allocator' against 'map'
    operator==(const new_allocator<_Tp>&, const new_allocator<_Tp>&)
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/allocator.h:128:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'allocator' against 'map'
    operator==(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/allocator.h:134:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'allocator' against 'map'
    operator==(const allocator<_Tp>&, const allocator<_Tp>&)
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:324:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '_Rb_tree_iterator' against 'map'
    operator==(const _Rb_tree_iterator<_Val>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:1273:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '_Rb_tree' against 'map'
    operator==(const _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/postypes.h:216:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'fpos' against 'map'
    operator==(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/basic_string.h:4902:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'map'
    operator==(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/basic_string.h:4909:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'map'
    operator==(const basic_string<_CharT>& __lhs,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/basic_string.h:4923:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >'
    operator==(const _CharT* __lhs,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/basic_string.h:4935:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'map'
    operator==(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/array:240:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'array' against 'map'
    operator==(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/tuple:915:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'tuple' against 'map'
    operator==(const tuple<_TElements...>& __t,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_map.h:1052:9: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'map<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2, type-parameter-0-3>' against 'char const[4]'
        operator==(const map<_K1, _T1, _C1, _A1>&,
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_multimap.h:974:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'multimap' against 'map'
    operator==(const multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:1511:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'vector' against 'map'
    operator==(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/../../../../include/c++/5.2.1/bits/random.tcc:2030:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'normal_distribution' against 'map'
    operator==(const std::normal_distribution<_RealType>& __d1,
    ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Hints:

- It's usually best to just check the documentation for the toplevel call from your code (`find` in test.cpp): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find
- disregard the candidates that get rejected. It's in the nature of ADL that loads of candidates are *obviously* not applicable. This is only useful if you need to debug your library code to find out *why* your own `operator==` overload was being rejected.

### Out Of The Box

If I guessed your API abuse correctly, here's a suggested fix:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65747056b17cb23a)</kbd>**

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using Map = map<string, int>;

int main() {
    vector<Map> maps;

    Map target { { "one", 1 }, { "two", 2 } };

    auto match = std::find_if(maps.begin(), maps.end(), [](Map const& m) { return m.end() != m.find("one"); });

    if (match != maps.end()) {
        for (auto const& p : *match) {
            std::cout << p.first << " -> " << p.second << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, given that `maps` is empty in the sample, nothing is printed.

Comment: Thanks, my issue was something very similar to what you expected. 
I had declared a `vector<map<string, int>> mapVector` and then tried to search it using `std::find(mapVector[1].begin(), mapVector[1].end(), target)`  but changing this to use the `std::map::find` function fixed my issue.  It ended up looking like: `mapVector[1].find(target)`